# Cordova Build Creates xcarchive not an ipa. Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Cordova to create and build my application. Today (12/12/17), I am using the current version of everything (cordova, xcode, etc). When I run:

> cordova build ios --device --release

at the end of the build process that happens, I get **no** errors. But I do get this message:

> Exported *myappname*.xcarchive to:
>   /Users/.../platforms/ios/build/device
>   ** EXPORT SUCCESS **

I don't see anywhere in build logs that a .ipa file was created. Just a stupid .xcarchive.

**Note**: I cannot to edit project information or settings in XCode manually, because I am running this Cordova command as part of automated build process. I should be able to create an .ipa via Cordova CLI, without having to open XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having the same experience I did, check the actual physical directory for the .ipa file.  Turns out even though my build log never said so, the .ipa file was actually being built alongside the .xcarchive.  It should be in /platforms/ios/build/device/*myappname*.ipa.